# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple When slicing 3D list with numpy in python

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, typeerror, numpy-slicing

So I have this 3D list in python that I want to slice. I'm using numpy. However I don't see a solution to this because the syntax seems correct and should in theory work. (This is a standard python list btw)

```
list = [
    [[0, 56, 78], [4, 86, 90], [7, 87, 34]],
    [[1, 49, 76], [0, 76, 78], [8, 60, 7]], 
    [[9, 6, 58], [6, 57, 78], [10, 46, 2]]
    ]

pair1 = 86, 90
pair2 = 76, 78

a_sliced = list[...,1:]

ix1 = np.flatnonzero((a_sliced  == pair1).all(-1).ravel()).item()
ix2 = np.flatnonzero((a_sliced  == pair2).all(-1).ravel()).item()

np.concatenate(tileMap)[ix1:ix2+1]
```

However when I run the code, I get the following error:

```
    a_sliced = list[...,1:]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Please help, I honestly don't know what I am doing wrong...

Comment: Deifine the list as a numpy array: `a = np.array(l)`. Then slice on the array, not the list: `a_sliced = a[...,1:]`.

Comment: It's a list, not a numpy array. You just need to convert it. BTW `list` is a bad variable name cause it shadows the builtin `list`.